# intento pasar mi vista show a pdf y no me muestra la informacion sino el codigo alguien sabe porque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

*les muestro mi controlador*

```
     def show
    @detalles = @factura.detalles
    @detalle = Detalle.new
    @color = Color.new
    @total = @factura.detalles.sum(:valor)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render   pdf: "pdf", file: "app/views/facturas/pdf.pdf.erb"
         end
    end
  end
```

*y tengo instaladas las gemas
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.6.5'*

*mi codigo de vista de show esta bien pero al momento de mostrar el pdf me sale lo mismo de mi vista *

[image: esto es lo que me muestra al generar el pdf]

Comment: Creo que `file` está de más. Si el controlador actual es `FacturasController`, con `render pdf: "nombredelarchivoagenerar"` debería bastar. Solo por saber, ¿la url que usas termina con `.pdf`?

Comment: asi tengo actualmente el controlador, manejandolo desde otra vista lo que quiero que me muestre en el pdf ,pero no me genera la informacion sino el codigo y no entiendo